# Swap elements python

Tags: python, list, sorting

Look at successive pair of elements in a list, and swaps them if they are out of order (possibly swapping a number more than once).

I have tried to use for loops, etc., but am unable to solve the problem.

deleted

I need to use functions rather than any python library. I can solve this using one (already have!) but I need to use low level beginner methods.

ex: bubble([2,1,4,3]) == [1,2,3,4]

Comment: so you're trying to implement bubble sort?

Comment: Can you show your code that you are currently stuck with?

Comment: The algorithm you are describing is called bubble sort. Here is a python implementation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-bubble-sort/

Comment: don't show implementation but rather pseudo code so OP can arrive at answer himself and get the benefit of learning --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation

Answer (score 0):

You could use the indices of the elements in order to swap them:

```
def swap(seq, idx, jdx):
    """swaps the two elements of the sequence, identified by their indices
    in-place, mutates seq
    return: None
    """
    seq[idx], seq[jdx] = seq[jdx], seq[idx]
```

The one liner that swaps the values creates a tuple of values on the right hand side, and unpacks it (assigns each values to a variable) on the left hand side.

Comment: This works because to python `a,b` is the equivalent of `(a,b)` or `tuple([a,b])`. And tuples are immutable, so the method of swapping shown in this answer doesn't "step on itself". Just clarifying for the OP.

Comment: gotta love Python for making even BubbleSort too easy

Answer (score 0):

```
value_list =[4,3,2,1]

for a in range(len(value_list)):
    for b in range(len(value_list)):
        if value_list[b] > value_list[a]:
            value_list[b],value_list[a]=value_list[a],value_list[b]

print(value_list)
```

you can use this within function like:

```
value_list =[4,3,2,1]
def sort_list(given_list):
    for a in range(len(given_list)):
        for b in range(len(given_list)):
            if given_list[b] > given_list[a]:
                given_list[b],given_list[a]=given_list[a],given_list[b]
    return given_list

print(sort_list(value_list))
```